# Improving a LaTeX CV by moving away from TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibliographies, latexmk, tikz-shape

A few years ago, I adapted a CV template from Overleaf to fit my needs. However, I think I'm stuck. Changing the data within the CV now takes a whole lot of work. I can see some problems but don't know how to tackle them:

The LaTeX code makes heavy use of TikZ:

- The flow text needs manual horizontal and vertical positioning, line breaks and italics/emphasis.
- The dates need manual positioning
- The colored bars extending downards from the circled FontAwesome icons need  manual lengths.
- The whole styling of categories and job entries is repetitive instead of using some sort of hierarchical commands.

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[]{cv}
% \usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\header{jack}{sparrow}{Ship Captain}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

  % Global styling
  \tikzstyle{every label}=[label distance=3pt, ]
  \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, out=90, in=-90]

  % Schemes
  \tikzstyle{section}=[inner sep=5pt, minimum size=20pt, circle]
  \tikzstyle{endsection}=[inner sep=0pt, draw=none]

  \node[section, label={0:\LARGE experience}, draw=red] (experience) at (0,0) {\LARGE \textcolor{black}{\faDesktop}};
  \node[endsection] (endexperience) at (0,-7.7) {};
  \path[draw=red] (experience) to[out=-90,in=90] (endexperience);

  \node[
    label={left:as of Oct 2003},
    label={right:\large Advanced Ship Captain, \normalsize \emph{Black Pearl}}
  ] (blackpearl) at (3,-1) {};

  \node[
    label={[align=left]right:Covert intelligence operations for national security.\\Infiltration from high-risk environments.}
  ] (blackpearl) at (3.2,-1.7) {};

  \node[
    label={left:1917\,-\,1920},
    label={right:\large Ship Captain, \normalsize \emph{Gray Pearl}}
  ] (graypearl) at (3,-3) {};

  \node[
    label={[align=left]right:Covert intelligence operations for national security.\\Utilization of advanced espionage techniques and gadgets.\\Surveillance, analysis, and threat prevention.}
  ] (graypearl2) at (3.2,-3.9) {};

  \node[
    label={left:Jan-May 1962},
    label={right:\large Ship Captain, \normalsize \emph{White Pearl Solutions Ltd.}}]
    (whitepearl) at (3,-5.2) {};

  \node[
    label={[align=left]right:Part of a project team;\\Trained extensively in planning and executing covert operations and infiltrating high-security areas.}]
    (whitepearl2) at (3.2,-5.9) {};    

  \node[
    label={left:1968\,-\,1973},
    label={right:Working student Secret Agent, \normalsize \emph{Colorless Pearl United}}]
    (colorlesspearl) at (3,-6.8) {};

  \node[
    label={left:1870\,-\,1980},
    label={right:Tutor for Secret Operations Team, \normalsize \emph{MI6 Training Facility,}}]
    (university) at (3,-7.4) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

  % Global styling
  \tikzstyle{every label}=[label distance=3pt, ]
  \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, out=90, in=-90]

  % Schemes
  \tikzstyle{section}=[inner sep=5pt, minimum size=20pt, circle]
  \tikzstyle{endsection}=[inner sep=0pt, draw=none]

  \node[section, label={0:\LARGE education}, draw=black] (education) at (0,0) {\LARGE \textcolor{red}{\faGraduationCap}};
  \node[endsection] (endeducation) at (0,-2.5) {};
  \path[draw=black] (education) to[out=-90,in=90] (endeducation);

  \node[
    label={left:1960},
    label={right:\large M.Sc. Secretive Operations, \normalsize \emph{MI6 Intelligence Agency}}]
    (master) at (3,-1) {};

  \node[
    label={left:1950},
    label={right:\large B.Sc. Secretive Operations, \normalsize \emph{MI6 Intelligence Agency}}]
    (master) at (3,-2) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    
      % Global styling
      \tikzstyle{every label}=[label distance=3pt, ]
      \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, out=90, in=-90]
    
      % Schemes
      \tikzstyle{section}=[inner sep=5pt, minimum size=20pt, circle]
      \tikzstyle{endsection}=[inner sep=0pt, draw=none]
    
      \node[section, label={0:\LARGE skills}, draw=red] (skills) at (0,0) {\LARGE \textcolor{black}{\faConnectdevelop}};
      \node[endsection] (endskills) at (0,-1.7) {};
      \path[draw=red] (skills) to[out=-90,in=90] (endskills);
    
      \node[
        label={right:Espionage Techniques, Surveillance, Java, Combat Training, Infiltration, Adaptability, Kubernetes}]
        (skill-names) at (1.5,-1) {};
          
  \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
  
    % Global styling
    \tikzstyle{every label}=[label distance=3pt, ]
    \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, out=90, in=-90]
  
    % Schemes
    \tikzstyle{section}=[inner sep=5pt, minimum size=20pt, circle]
    \tikzstyle{endsection}=[inner sep=0pt, draw=none]
  
    \node[section, label={0:\LARGE interests}, draw=black] (interests) at (0,0) {\LARGE \textcolor{red}{\faCubes}};
    \node[endsection] (endinterests) at (0,-1.7) {};
    \path[draw=black] (interests) to[out=-90,in=90] (endinterests);
  
    \node[
      label={right:Problem Solving, Teamwork, Adaptability, Question Asking}]
      (raspi) at (1.5,-1) {};
        
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
  
    % Global styling
    \tikzstyle{every label}=[label distance=3pt, ]
    \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, out=90, in=-90]
  
    % Schemes
    \tikzstyle{section}=[inner sep=5pt, minimum size=20pt, circle]
    \tikzstyle{endsection}=[inner sep=0pt, draw=none]
  
    \node[section, label={0:\LARGE contact}, draw=red] (contact) at (0,0) {\LARGE \textcolor{black}{\faAt}};
    \node[endsection] (endcontact) at (0,-3.7) {};
    \path[draw=red] (contact) to[out=-90,in=90] (endcontact);
  
    \node[
      label={right:James Bond}]
      (mail) at (1.5,-1) {};

    \node[
      label={right:MI6 Headquarters, London, United Kingdom}]
      (mail) at (1.5,-1.5) {};

    \node[
      label={right:Some more text}]
      (mail) at (1.5,-2) {};

    \node[
      label={right:\href{mailto:james.bond@mi6.gov}{james.bond@mi6.gov}}]
      (mail) at (1.5,-2.5) {};

    \node[
      label={right:+44 2071 2345 67}]
      (phone) at (1.5,-3) {};

    \node[
      label={right:\href{https://www.linkedin.com/profile}{linkedin} / \href{https://www.xing.com/profile/James_Bond}{xing}}]
      (linkedin) at (1.5,-3.5) {};    
        
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Part of the styling is defined in a class file. There's dead code, especially regarding the bibliography, but throwing it out completely breaks the build.

`cv.cls`

```
\ProvidesClass{cv}[28.11.2019 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}
\definecolor{futureblue}{HTML}{3A86B7}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF7900}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{217, 24, 40}

% \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{brown}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  % \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{red}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Roboto Thin}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Roboto}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Roboto}

%\setmathfont{XITS Math}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \thinfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    % \node[anchor=west, circle, draw=white,
    %   path picture={
    %     \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
    %       \includegraphics[width=4cm]{profile}
    %     };
    %   };
    % ] {asd};
    \node[circle, minimum size=3cm,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=3cm]{james_bond_avatar.png}
               };
           }] (pic) at (0.75,0.4) {};
    % \node (brush) at (12.6,0.25) {
    %     \includegraphics[width=3.7cm]{brush}
    % };
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {
      \fontsize{40pt}{300pt}\color{header}
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont #2}
    };
    % \node [anchor=east] (vorname) at (box) {%
    %     \fontsize{40pt}\color{header}%
    %     {\thinfont #1}
    % };
    % \node [anchor=west] (nachname) at (box) {%
    %     \fontsize{140pt}\color{header}%
    %     {\takota  #2}
    % };

    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
      \thinfont #3%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{2.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Structure %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        brown\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont%
    % \@sectioncolor 
    #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

% \renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
%   \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
%   {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1}
%   \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
% }

% \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[2]{
%   \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
%   {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2}
%   \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
% }

\pagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
}

\defbibheading{bibheading}[\bibname]{%
   \subsubsection*{#1}
   \markboth{#1}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=bibheading]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Other tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[left=1.5cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

% \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{00b5be}

% \colorlet{myurlcolor}{Aquamarine}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=xitasored,
  filecolor=xitasored
}
    
% A fix for \href{}{} colors not working with fontspec
\makeatletter
\def\HyColor@@@@UseColor#1\@nil{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}
\makeatother
```

I don't know how to either move away from TikZ for the flow text or embed some kind of 'normal' LaTeX so that line breaks, margins etc happen automatically. This would probably also improve how the text gets highlighted when a reader tries to copy-paste.

Any pointers here would be welcome.

I use this as placeholder image, see `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{james_bond_avatar.png}`:
https://ibb.co/cy2G3tr

I use VSCode/LaTeX Workshop, which runs `LatexMk`, outputting:
`Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "...path/main.tex"'`